# Help with MvcContrib Column options

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib-grid

I am using the MVCContrib grid and I would like to add some html attributes to a cell depending on the value of a column. I need something like this

```
 column.For(c => c.Type.Equals("Type A") ? 
     "show value and add attribute" : "just show value");
```

I tried this but it doesn't work. It shows the value on the grid as - class="Type A"

```
column.For(c => c.Type.Equals("Type A") ? c.Type.AsClassAttribute() : c.Type);
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this with jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
column.For(c => (c.Type.Equals("Type A") ? c.Type.AsClassAttribute() : c.Type));
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Same output as I was getting, it shows on the table like class="Type A"